# Subclassing UITextField to include a picker and a toolbar

Tags: ios, swift

## Problem

I have an application that has a user registration view. It has many `UITextField`, and many of these have a picker with a toolbar embedded to close the picker i.e:

```swift
myTextField.inputView = myPicker
myTextField.inputAccessoryView = myToolbar
```

Essentially I want to reuse these text fields in different parts of my application, so I thought of subclassing `UITextField`, something like `PickerUITextField`.

## Attempt

I've tried something like this:

```swift
class PickerUITextField: UITextField {
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        withToolbar()
        self.inputView = self.picker
        self.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar
    }

    private func withToolbar() {
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolbar.isTranslucent = true
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
                                    target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done,
                                         target: self, action: #selector(removeToolBar))

        toolbar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
    }

    @objc func removeToolBar() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

## Question

However, how can I detect in the view controller that the user has pressed the "Done" button of my `PickerUITextField`? In other words:

```swift
class UserRegistrationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var country: PickerUITextField!

    // I want this to be triggered whenever the country picker closes
    func didSelectCountry() {
      print("User selected \(country.text!)")
    }

}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a closure in PickerUITextField to perform done button action.

```
class PickerUITextField: UITextField {
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    var doneBtnAction:(() -> Void)?


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        withToolbar()
        self.inputView = self.picker
        self.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar
    }

    private func withToolbar() {
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolbar.isTranslucent = true
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
                                    target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done,
                                         target: self, action: #selector(removeToolBar))

        toolbar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
    }

    @objc func removeToolBar() {
        doneBtnAction?()
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

And in your view controller, you can assign a closure. It will be called when you tap the done button.

```
class UserRegistrationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var country: PickerUITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        country.doneBtnAction = { [weak self] in
            print("User selected \(self?.country.text!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if let`ting the `doneBtnAction` you could simply say `doneBtnAction?()` btw. :)

Comment: @AndréSlotta yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a protocol/delegate:

```
protocol PickerUITextFieldDelegate: class {
    func didSelectCountry()
}

class PickerUITextField: UITextField {

    // UITextField already have a 'delegate' we need a different name
    weak var pickerDelegate: PickerUITextFieldDelegate?

    let picker = UIPickerView()
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()

    @objc func removeToolBar() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()

        self.pickerDelegate?.didSelectCountry()
    }
}

// We need to implement the PickerUITextFieldDelegate delegate here:
class UserRegistrationViewController: UIViewController, PickerUITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var country: PickerUITextField!

    // Don't forget to set the delegate!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.country.pickerDelegate = self
    }

    // This will now be triggered by the delegate
    func didSelectCountry() {
        print("User selected \(country.text!)")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @bauerMusic, but what if I now have multiple `PickerUITextField` in the same view controller?

Say I have `country`, `city`, `age` all of type `PickerUITextField` in the same view controller. In the `removeToolbar()`function I would have to call the three `didSelectCountry()`, `didSelectCity()`, and `didSelectAge()`, even though only one would be actually pressed, no?

Comment: @J.Doe How about `didSelect(type: Enum)` where you can set each `TextField` its own type. Since you sub `UITextField`, you can add a 'type' var, and set each accordingly. The delegate will then do something like: `self.pickerDelegate?.didSelect(self.type)`